# What happened to Loki after he fell from the bridge in Asgard (Thor, 2011)?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, marvel, thor-marvel, loki

After Loki fell from the crystal bridge in Asgard..

[image]

in the post-credits of *Thor (2011)*, he was seen in the mirror, apparently possessing Dr. Selvig to gain information on the Tesseract..

[image]

**The question is where did Loki end up falling?**

Comment: Related, arguable dupe: [Where was Loki at the beginning of the Avengers?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/17577/5184)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After the events in *Thor (2011)* where Loki fell from the crystal bridge, as mentioned in the [MCU wikia](http://marvelcinematicuniverse.wikia.com/wiki/Loki#Losing_All_Hope),

> Loki, devastated by Odin's repudiation of his actions, let go of Thor on purpose and fell into the abyss made by the destruction of the Bifrost Bridge.

[He fell to the Wormhole](http://marvelcinematicuniverse.wikia.com/wiki/Loki#New_Alliance), and..

> ..arrived in a part of the universe called [Sanctuary](http://marvelcinematicuniverse.wikia.com/wiki/Sanctuary) and met the Mad Titan Thanos, who offered a pact that would allow him to become ruler of the Earth while he would take the Tesseract which was being studied by S.H.I.E.L.D.. Thanos provided Loki with a Scepter with a blue gem which acted as a powerful weapon, and also as a mind control device.

[image]

After these follows the events in *Marvel's The Avengers (2012)*.

Comment: Of note, that portion of the unofficial wikia you've cited is not cited itself. Where is this information actually *from*? This time period is not depicted in any of the movies or one-shots. We know that he falls, we know that he shows up in Sanctuary - but as you asked, is that where he fell *to*? Did he go on an intergalactic road trip afterwards? Did he go to Tahiti for a bit?

Comment: @phantom42 I can see him taking a detour through Tahiti. I hear it's a magical place.

Comment: @phantom42 The wiki said he got through the wormhole and **arrived** at the sanctuary. so it was like entering a slide tube, then you arrive at the pool..

Comment: Yes, but the wiki is *unsourced*. It seems to be speculating on events we are never shown. The author assumes that to be the case, but cites nothing to prove that it *was* the case.

Answer (score 2):

Source: I wrote several scenes for 2011's *Thor*, including this one.

Loki - who, even falling to his possible death, still grabs for and catches a symbol of power that he can't even *use* - deliberately lets go and falls away.  And I couldn't stand the idea of him drifting around in space. It's that simple.  So I suggested a wormhole, just that he fall away *to someplace*, anyplace, just not lost and drifting around forever.

Yeah, I worked through a lot of stuff writing it.  It was still supposed to be darker; the shot where Thor, after Loki falls, looks up at his father, it was originally supposed to be Odin being more severe, less gentle, making Thor look up and say:

"Please don't kill me."

Comment: Making that claim under an anonymous account is not really valid as a source. Can you provide some third party proof that you were one of the screenwriters for *Thor (2011)*?